# Combining a list of tuples

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to combine the values of this list by key

```
List((1, 11), (2, 21), (1, 13), (1, 14), (2, 25))
```

and obtain a list like this:

```
List((1, List(11, 13, 14)), (2, List(21, 25)))
```

I am thinking of using a groupBy and then a reduceLeft for each element, but I think there may be an easier, more direct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val l = List((1, 11), (2, 21), (1, 13), (1, 14), (2, 25))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,11), (2,21), (1,13), (1,14), (2,25))


scala> l.groupBy(_._1).toList.map(xs => (xs._1, xs._2.map(t => t._2)))
res0: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((2,List(21, 25)), (1,List(11, 13, 14)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @Brians solution, but uses pattern matching:

```
scala> val xs = List((1, 11), (2, 21), (1, 13), (1, 14), (2, 25))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,11), (2,21), (1,13), (1,14), (2,25))

xs.groupBy(_._1).toList.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2)) }
res13: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((1,List(11, 13, 14)), (2,List(21, 25)))
```

If you are ok with Map as result type you can shorten it a bit:

```
xs.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2))}
```

or:

```
xs.groupBy(_._1).map { t => (t._1, t._2.map(_._2))}
```